# difference between print() and print in python 2.7.10

Tags: python, python-2.7, printing

I am using python2.7.

When I ran the `.py` file:

```
def main():
    today = "Sunnday"
    print ("Today is", today, ".")

main()
```

I got: ('Today is', 'Sunnday', '.')

And when I ran with `print` no `()`:

```
def main():
    today = "Sunnday"
    print "Today is", today, "."

main()
```

Today is Sunnday .

May I know what is the difference between `print` and `print()`?

Comment: `print` in Python 2 is a statement, not a function. `print('foo', 'bar')` is actually printing the tuple `('foo', 'bar')`, which happens to work as expected if you `print` only one thing.

Answer (score 1):

In Python 2, `print` is a statement.  When you say `print (3, 4, 5)`, you are printing the tuple `(3, 4, 5)`.  When, however, you say `print 3, 4, 5`, the numbers are separate arguments to `print` that are each printed.  If you were to do `print (3)`, however, the parentheses are grouping just like in mathematics.  That means that it is the same thing as `print 3` and the parentheses are not printed.  To print a one-element tuple, it would be `print (3,)`